# Rails 3.0.20 app not allowing IE to store cookies

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, internet-explorer, session-cookies

I have an app that uses a session to store an ID for the user, standard practice for most login systems.  The app has worked in IE before.  I'm using Heroku to host.

I recently updated the rails version to 3.0.20 because of the security concerns, and it seems that IE will not allow any cookie to be set.  Cookies are stored just fine in Firefox/Chrome/Safari, but IE will not store them.

There are no underscores in the subdomain, so that's not an issue.

As far as I know the only recent change was updating the rails version to 3.0.20, which leads me to suspect there's something amiss there.  Since rails 3.0.20 was created to address a security concern, I'm curious if the security changes made IE think the app is a security violation and will no longer accept cookies from it?  However, I even tested IE where I told it to accept all cookies from every site, so I'm not sure what's going on here.

Anyone seen this issue recently or aware of what may be going on?

There's no stack trace or errors to show; cookies just aren't being set, which results in a standard "record not found" error.

Comment: Blind guess: are you embedding your site within other pages using iFrames?

Comment: Why did you ask this, Martin, what is your theory?